# Unit Code testing of internal functions

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, xctest

I am a newbie on testing and so I am stumbling about testing internal functionality on some code parts. How to test ONLY the privateParseAndCheck and/or privateFurtherProcessing functionality with different input, but I dont want it as public functions?

```
-(BOOL) publicFunction()
{
   //some stuff with network
   NSError* error;
   NSData* data = load(&error);
  //now I got data and parse and check
  BOOL result = privateParseAndCheck(data, error, ...);

  if( result ) {
    privateFurtherProcessing();
  }
  return result;
}
```

Is re-writing the code the solution? I am also interested in some experiences with the tips/solutions on Xcode Server.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a straightforward way to test what you want only from public methods, do so.

If not, you have a choice: You can expose the method only to test code. *This is common practice, but I do not recommend this.* It inhibits the other option…

Or, expose the method completely. If this makes you feel uncomfortable, **there is probably a class trying to get out.** Extract the class (the methods you want to test and whatever else makes sense to go with them.) You can now test that class.

This is especially helpful when coming up with different conditions (such as different errors) is difficult. Extract, and it's easy.

Further reading: [Testability, Information Hiding, and the Class Trying to Get Out](https://qualitycoding.org/testability-vs-hiding/)